# Get DataGrid cell from mouse position

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagrid

I want to get the clicked cell of a `DataGrid` at the `MouseDown` event. So far I haven't been successful.
I tried

- `dg.CurrentCell` - contains the previous clicked cell
- `dg.GetChildAt(...)` - doesn't work because the cells are not listed as children of the DataGrid

Comment: Did you make a question and answer it right away, with an answer from `msdn` site, and dozen links on simple google search?

Comment: @Claudius did you notice that all the google results refer to DataGrid**View** instead of DataGrid? If you add -datagridview to the search, every result is for WPF and so on...

Comment: But what is the difference if both grab same event `Mouse.MouseDown`?

Comment: well, what is the difference between a button and a datagridview? they both have the `MouseDown`-event... `DataGridView` is a lot more enhanced than `DataGrid`, maybe that's also why there isn't many help about `DataGrid` in forums or on SO

Comment: @Claudius I have to admit: when searching for the title and seeing that `DataGridView.HitTest` exists it could come to your mind that `DataGrid.HitTest` is worth looking up, but for anybody searching for the title plus `-datagridview -wpf` (to get results for `DataGrid`) the question might be helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`HitTest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8yw7fbd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the cell that the mouse is over. (It is not dependant on the `MouseDown`-Event, you just need the mouse position relative to the DataGrid)

example:

```
Private Sub dg_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles dg.MouseDown
    Dim htinfo As HitTestInfo = dg.HitTest(new Point(e.X, e.Y))

    If htinfo.Type = HitTestType.Cell Then
        Dim clickedCell As DataGridCell = dg.Item(htinfo.Row, htinfo.Column)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't `clickedCell` be of type `DataGridViewCell`?

Comment: @CrazyIvan1974 I was unfortunately bound to the ancient `DataGrid` WinForms control. I'm joyful if it also works for `DataGridView`

Comment: Yeah, wow, my mistake.  I see *NOW* that this topic is not about the `DataGridView`.  Blew right past the main topic. This *DOES* work with `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 1):

```
   Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseDown
    Try
        With DataGridView1
            .Rows(.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex).Selected = True
        End With
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```